# Using a supervised learning to compare two conditions

Tags: machine-learning, experiment-design, supervised-learning

I've got to analyze data about two signals x and y using machine learning but am stuck with how to proceed. Conditions are:

1) signal x and y are known to be linked to one another, but no parametric model exists

2) we performed a manipulation in the system to see whether the manipulation changes the relationship between x and y.

My hypothesis is that the manipulation decreases the link between x and y compared to baseline condition (no manipulation).

Since no parametric model exists, I use a machine learning algorithm to approximate the function to map x to y. Then I want to show that model performance is worse in the manipulation condition, expected for the hypothesis that the manipulation decreases the link between x and y.

My question is, how should I use a machine learning algorithm here? More precisely, which in the following do you think I should do?

A) Fit a ML separately in baseline and manipulation conditions, and compare cross-validation scores between these two

B) Fit a ML only in baseline condition and test in manipulation condition to see if information to predict y in x is lost in manipulation condition (showing that prediction accuracy in manipulation condition is worse than cross-validation score in baseline)

Comment: Can you give us some more details about the problem / data. What are these x and y? How are they linked? How did you manipulate the system?

Comment: Essentially x and y are brain activity signals in two different brain regions (same dimension), and the manipulation is to apply a certain type of drug to see how the relationship between the activity in those two brain regions is altered.

Comment: So what exactly are you comparing? Link? What is that? What kind of variable? Also why do you say that no parametric model exists?